# How to re-inject chrome extension scripts when the page url changes?

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

My chrome extension won't re-inject my content script into the page when I click on a new link. Only when I refresh the page the content script is injected into the new link, but still won't work when I click on a new link.

manifest.json

```
    {
        "manifest_version": 3,
        "name": "Test",
        "description": "Test.",
        "version": "1.0",
        "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting", "tabs", "webNavigation"],
        "content_scripts": [{
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["etsy-replies.js", "background.js"],
            "css" : ["stylesheet.css"]
        }],
        "background": {
          "service_worker": "background.js"
        },
        "web_accessible_resources": [
            {
              "resources": [ "etsy-replies.js", "popup.html", "stylesheet.css", "background.js" ],
              "matches": [ "https://www.etsy.com/*" ]
            }
          ]
      }
```

background.js

```
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,changeInfo,tab){
      if (tab.url.indexOf("https://www.etsy.com/*") > -1 && 
          changeInfo.url === undefined){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "etsy-replies.js"} );
      }
    });
```

Updated test code

```
    async function reloadUrl() {
        await navigation.reload({
            info: { animation: "fade-in" },
            state: { infoPaneOpen: true },
        }); 
    }

navigation.addEventListener("navigate", reloadUrl)
```

Comment: Remove `*` in indexOf.

Comment: @wOxxOm it still doesn't seem to work. Is the background js code correct? It's meant to detect if the tab has updated and if so it'll reload the script.

Comment: Indeed the entire condition doesn't make sense. Actually you don't need the background script at all because you can listen to `navigation.onnavigate` event in your content script. Also don't ever include background.js anywhere except `background` section of manifest.json.

Comment: @wOxxOm gotcha, thx for the helpful tips. I tried what you said but when I click on a new link I immediately get the "aw, snap" chrome error. The page loads fine initially though. I've added the code I tried to the post under "Updated test code", I couldn't add it to this comment.

Comment: @wOxxOm don't worry my smooth brain figured it out. thanks for the help!